# Problems connecting MIDI DJ controller

Tags: audio, usb-audio, midi

I have  a Traktor Kontrol S5 and I really need to use it with Linux (in my case Linux Mint). Also, Im new to Linux.
The problem is that, even if Ive installed the driver, the MIDI part of the controller doesnt work, while the audio part does. So if I want to play audio through it, it works, but MIDI wise seems disconnected.
I tried running the command `amidi -l` and the interface doesnt show.

But if I run `cat /proc/asound/cards` the USB sound card works.
I have no idea how to fix it, and I cant find anything similar online.

I tried `dmesg`
In the output I found:

```
[ 2611.444069] hid-generic 0003:17CC:1420.0005: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Native Instruments  Traktor Kontrol S5] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
[ 2625.321568] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.321589] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8ea0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8eb0 trb-end 00000001a4aa8eb0 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.321692] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 2625.321815] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.321828] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8eb0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8ec0 trb-end 00000001a4aa8ec0 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.321845] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.321855] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8ec0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8ed0 trb-end 00000001a4aa8ed0 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322190] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.322204] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8ed0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8ee0 trb-end 00000001a4aa8ee0 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322219] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.322229] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8ee0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8ef0 trb-end 00000001a4aa8ef0 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322243] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.322252] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8ef0 trb-start 00000001a4aa8f00 trb-end 00000001a4aa8f00 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322523] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.322534] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8f00 trb-start 00000001a4aa8f10 trb-end 00000001a4aa8f10 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322549] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
[ 2625.322558] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Looking for event-dma 00000001a4aa8f10 trb-start 00000001a4aa8f20 trb-end 00000001a4aa8f20 seg-start 00000001a4aa8000 seg-end 00000001a4aa8ff0
[ 2625.322592] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 1 comp_code 1
```

Just for the record, I also have a MIDI keyboard and actually works fine

Any help would be awesome, thanks in advance

Comment: Hm... Do these xhci_hcd errors disappear when you don't plug in the midi controller? I'm a bit surprised that would be a USB3 device, that's why I'm asking. Also, which kernel version is your Mint using? (`uname -r` will tell you) Asking because I remember something similar being fixed quite a while back, but for an USB3 wifi controller (Kernel 4.something, some mediatek wifi controller, can't fully recall).

Comment: @MarcusMüller the kernel version is 5.15.0-56-lowlatency.
I tried running again dmesg and the output is quite different but the xhci errors remain, so its probably not it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just noticed that my controller isnt actually MIDI but HID. Could this be the problem?

Comment: a MIDI controller is a HID, human interface device.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so it  should still be listed in the MIDI devices (with amidi -l) right?

Comment: as said, I'm trying to figure out whether the errors we see have something to do with your MIDI controller or not.

Comment: Am I getting too old for the MIDI stuff ? Are modern documentations of modern hardware just out of the capabilities of my understanding ? This is possible ! Anyway… after parsing (diagonally) the Traktor Kontrol S5 's user manual… I just failed to read anything regarding possible midi inputs/outputs. Is this device actually capable of exchanging midi events with its environment ?